# How do I properly upload a Python executable file to GitHub?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I've compiled a program I've made with Python using `cx_Freeze`. I want to upload this program to a GitHub repository and I'm aware that I should use the "releases" feature. However, my executable file comes with *many* other files. Additionally, GitHub doesn't process some of the files(which came with my executable) I try to upload.

Is there even a way to do such a thing? Or is this not supposed to be done? If so, how else can I distribute my executable programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upload your "distributables" as a ZIP file. You should also consider building an installer that copies all of the files to their correct location on the user's file system.